# get the value based on two fields form single table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table user with below fields .

```
 id user_name   team       onsite_offshore 
 1   xxx        US East     offshore
 2   YYY        US East     onsite
 3   zzz        US East     onsite
 4   aaa        Us West     onsite
 5   bbb        US West     offshore
```

I have two dependency dropdown  geo and location with geo values 'US East' and 'US West'  and 
location value 'US East and premisis' for'US East'

'US West and premisis' for 'US West dropdown'.

geo        Location
US East - US East,offshore(display as 2 options one by one)
US West - US West and offshore(display as 2 options one by one)

```
  on choosing US East in localtion  with geo 'US East' dropdow I want to load the value 'yyy,zzz' which is not inluded in offshore(which is in same table with different column.)
       on choosing offshore in localtion dropdown for geo 'US EASt'I want to load the value 'XXX' which is should inluded in offshore(which is in same table with different column.)

  on choosing US West in localtion  with geo 'US West' dropdown I want to load the value 'aaa' which is not inluded in offshore(which is in same table with different column.)
       on choosing offshore in localtion dropdown for geo 'US West' I want to load the value 'bbb' which is should inluded in offshore(which is in same table with different column.)

$filter_team_details=DB::table('user_master')->leftjoin('user_teams','user_teams.team','=','user_master.geo')->whereIn('user_teams.team',$teams)->groupBy('user_teams.team')->pluck('user_teams.team')->toArray(); (In this query I want to check for onsite_offshore condition in same query )
```

Is it possible to check both condition single table as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using `whereIn` , Your query can be simple written like this for muliple condition :

```
    $filter_team_details = DB::table('user_master')
                           ->leftjoin('user_teams','user_teams.team','=','user_master.geo')
                           ->where('user_teams.team',$teams)
                           ->where('user_teams.onsite_offshore',$nameOfyourVariable)
                           ->groupBy('user_teams.team')
                           ->pluck('user_teams.team')
                           ->toArray();
```

Although You can use `whereIn` if you wish, I hope it is helpful for you :)